# Determine if this interpretation satisfies axiom Congruent axiom 1

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Recall the interpretation of the rational plane: points are ordered pairs $(x, y)$ with
$x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$; lines are solution sets of equations $ax + by + c = 0$ with $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a, b$ not both zero; $(x, y)$ is incident to $ax + by + c = 0$ if the ordered pair satisfies the equation; and betweenness is the standard Euclidean notion. We showed (or at least stated) that this interpretation is a model of incidence geometry with betweenness, i.e.,the incidence and betweenness axioms are all satisfied. Let’s declare two segments to be congruent if they have the same Euclidean length.

Determine if this interpretation satisfies axiom $C-1$. If so, prove it. If not, find specific. examples of $A, B, A'$and $r$ such that there is not a unique $B'$satisfying $AB \equiv A'B'.$

Comment: You'll need to explain a lot more than that. What is C-1? What effort and/or research did you put into this?

Comment: Are you using [Hilbert's axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_axioms) for geometry ? If so, is C-1 the first **Congruence's axiom** ?

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow im sorry is my first time posting. I dont know where to start to be honest

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it cannot.

Consider the line $x-y=0$ (i.e. $a=1, b=-1, c=0$). Consider the two points on the line : $A(0,0)$ and $B(1,1)$.

Consider now the line $r$ : $y=0$ (the $x$ axis) and on it the point $A'(0,0)$.

Then, you cannot find on $r$ a point $B'$ such that $A'B' \equiv AB$ because the lenght of this segment is $\sqrt 2$ and the point with coordinates $(\sqrt 2,0)$ has not both coordinates in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: could you help me with this two problems us well http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986557/justify-each-step-in-the-following-proof-of-proposition-3-9-b-i-like-to-know   and    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986502/justify-each-step-in-the-following-proof-of-proposition-3-9-a-i-like-to-know